# Embedding a Tableau viz in a different domain than that of tableau server without enabling third party cookies

Tags: cors, tableau-api, third-party-cookies

I currently have a tableau viz embedded into  an app within my company's domain, so both tableau and the app are within the same domain,

ex:
tableau server: https://www.tableau.example1.io and
app Url : https://www.example1.com/app

so with the above I am able to see the charts with no issues.

However have an ask which is to embed a tableau viz from a tableau server into another domain different from the tableau server ,

ex:
when I embed this
tableau server: https://www.tableau.example1.io
into this app URL: https://www.example2.com/app.

i get this message
[image: cors block]
I was able to go around this issue and achieve this by enabling third party cookies and then i was able to see the charts, however the requirement is to achieve this without enabling third party cookies, could anyone suggest if this is possible?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, sorry, i just corrected the post thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If would work if the embedded server used [partitioned cookies](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips).

Comment: so these partitioned cookies would work if there is a sub domain under the parent domain right? but my issue is that both of the domains are completely different domains, like one is google.com and the other is microsoft.com, and https:tableau.google.io was able to be embedded without enabling third party cookies in www.google.com, but I want https://tableau.google.io into work on www.microsoft.com without enabling third party cookies.

Comment: The warning messages you shared seem unrelated to 3rd-party cookie blocking (which is about privacy), because they speak about synchronous (blocking) cross-site requests, which are bad for performance. Cookie partitioning would have no effect on that. Do you observe blocked third-party cookies in your DevTools?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, you are right, those have nothing to do with the third party cookies, i just blocked third party cookies and the charts still came through, not sure what happenned, but these didn't come through a month ago when third party cookies were blocked, they came through after i enabled allow third party cookies, today i was able to view them even though i blocked third party cookies which is very wierd.